# T-SQL in sql 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the following in sql 2008.

[image]

Here is my logic :

Table 1 is source table.

IF match (domain & company & country) with Table 2 -> will update the price

Else

if match (domain) with Table 3 -> will update the price

else if match (domain) with Table 2 -> will update the price

else if match (company & country) with Table 2 -> will update the price

If match one of the above condition, will update the price in the source table.

How should i loop the source table ?
There may be a lot records in source table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you should loop. Try and build your query as a select query using CASE or similar to join based on your "matches". Then once you've build the select, change the select into an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it I think:

```
UPDATE T1
SET Price = CASE
    WHEN T2.Id IS NOT NULL THEN T2.Price
    WHEN T3.Id IS NOT NULL THEN T3.Price
    WHEN T22.Id IS NOT NULL THEN T22.Price
    ELSE T1.Price END
FROM [Table 1] T1
LEFT
JOIN [Table 2] T2
        ON  T1.Company = T2.Company
        AND T1.Country = T2.Country
        AND SUBSTRING(T1.Email, CHARINDEX('@', T1.Email) + 1, LEN(T1.Email)) = T2.Domain
LEFT
JOIN [Table 3] T3
        ON SUBSTRING(T1.Email, CHARINDEX('@', T1.Email) + 1, LEN(T1.Email)) = T3.Domain
LEFT
JOIN [Table 2] T22
        ON  T1.Company = T2.Company
        AND T1.Country = T2.Country
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I haven't bothered to write or test code, but if the above solution gives you correct results, you should consider adding a WHERE clause testing for the same conditions.    That way you won't do the work of updating rows where the original values aren't going to change.

There is no need to loop.    The UPDATE will apply to every row in T1 not filtered out by the JOINS or by a WHERE clause.